# Как найти индекс значения, если это значение входит в список?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Есть список:

```
d = {
   'name': ['mike, rick, morty', 'tot, piter, carl', 
            'brick, nick', 'rick, reaven, bart, homer', 'rick, morty'],
   'Date': ['11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', 
   '9/30/2009'], 
   'Address': ['AR', 'YU', 'RU', 'EU', 'BY']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Как найти индекс строки, где значение `name` равно `'tot, piter, carl'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Вариант 1:

```
In [206]: df.query("name == 'tot, piter, carl'").index
Out[206]: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

#### Вариант 2:

```
In [208]: df.index[df["name"].eq("tot, piter, carl")]
Out[208]: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

#### Вариант 3:

```
In [210]: df.loc[df["name"].eq("tot, piter, carl")].index
Out[210]: Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 3):

в дополнение к предыдущим еще один вариант, хотя неказистый, но, вроде, тоже рабочий:

```
pd.Series(index=df.name).index.get_loc('tot, piter, carl')
```